# Angular JS not updating or re drawing class

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here I have a snippet (below).
What it does is, when you click on body the first item("Hello World ") is made green, and when I click on the button "clicky" I am removing the first item, by popping an element in annotations, and angularJS re renders the HTML after the watch cycle, when it does it holds the same green style for the first element. I was expecting angular to re draw all the elements from scratch from the template present in ng-repeat tree. that would return all the "Hello World" being red than green.
Am I missing something very basic?

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <title>
        Kaboom
    </title>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js" />
    <script>
    </script>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

        $scope.annotations = [
          {id: -1, name:"Hello World"},
          {id: -2, name:"Hello World"},
          {id: -3, name:"Hello World"}
        ];

        $scope.remove = function() {
            $scope.annotations.splice(0,1);
            console.log($scope.annotations);
        }
    });
    </script>

    <script>

      function change() {

          var children = document.getElementById("test").children;
          console.log(children);
          children[0].setAttribute("class", "green");
      }

    </script>
    <style>
      .red {
        color: red;
      }

      .green {
        color: green;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onclick = "change()" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div id = "test" ng-repeat="t in annotations track by $index">
        <div class = "red" id = "{{t.id}}" >{{t.name}}</div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="clicky" ng-click = "remove()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
Here what is happening is that whenever you hit **clicky** button,
it goes to `$scope.remove = function() {
            $scope.annotations.splice(0,1);
            console.log($scope.annotations);
        }`

and also you have applied class red when you clicks on Hello world it calls the change() function which in turn turns green the first element of children which is now element with id="-2",
Your first element is successfully getting removed but since the remove() function reflects the first element of children so it turns it green every time.

Always make sure the function you are using to perform something should be very specific.

```html
   <html>

  <head>
    <title>
        Kaboom
    </title>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js" >
    </script>

    <script>

      function change12() {

          var children = document.getElementById("test").children;
          console.log(children);
          children[0].setAttribute("class", "green");
      }

    </script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

        $scope.annotations = [
          {id: -1, name:"Hello 1"},
          {id: -2, name:"Hello 2"},
          {id: -3, name:"Hello 3"}
        ];
        $scope.remove = function() {
            $scope.annotations.splice(0,1);
            console.log($scope.annotations);
        }
    });
    </script>

    <style>
      .red {
        color: red;
      }

      .green {
        color: green;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div id = "test" ng-repeat="t in annotations track by $index">
        <div class = "red" id = "{{t.id}}" onclick = "change12()">{{t.name}}</div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="clicky" ng-click = "remove()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Try executing this code,
you will understand
**The query you wrote in change() executes each time you call remove function in script on the first element present at that instant.So clicking the button do splice it but also calls the change() since you have given change() function to body so input button is also part of body,Change applies to all inside body.**

Thank you